# how maven version working, can't update ojdbc8 version

Tags: maven, ojdbc

Example code:
https://github.com/yszzu1/mvn-version-test

## Question:

### 1. why the admin-module always **using ojdbc8 19.3.0.0** ?

```sh
# mvn dependency:tree

[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ admin-module ---
[INFO] org.example:admin-module:jar:3.12.0
[INFO] +- org.example:db-module:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:19.3.0.0:compile
```

as we can see that the db-module is using `19.9.0.0`

### 2. even after upgrade the db-module `pom.xml` with

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>21.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

, the admin-module `mvn dependency:tree` is still showing **19.3.0.0**

### mvn & windows & JVM version:

```sh
# mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
Maven home: C:\Users\shuayan\Documents\open\apache-maven-3.8.5
Java version: 1.8.0_321, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_321\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

BTW: I have read these two wiki
https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/faq.html
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN401

Comment: One hint about your project: This: `<version>${gversion}</version>`. does not work... at all...

Comment: please run `mvn dependency:tree`  at project root dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how dependency management works in maven.

1. you have defined direct ojdbc8 dependency for db-module and it does work as expected
2. for admin-module the situation is "bit different":

- it depends directly on db-module, and ojdbc8 is now a transitive dependency
- it inherits ojdbc8 version from spring-boot-starter-parent (actually from spring-boot-dependencies)

if you really want to use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent you need to configure your project in the following way:

/pom.xml:

```xml
    <properties>
        ...
        <ojdbc.version>21.1.0.0</ojdbc.version>
        <oracle-database.version>21.1.0.0</oracle-database.version>
        ...
    </properties>
```

/db-module/pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <!-- omit version information -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: wow,  many thanks.  I met this problem many times from time to time.  `spring-boot-dependencies-2.3.7.RELEASE.pom`