# Can we both import and use as a dependency a pom artifactid (pom or jar)

Tags: maven, dependency-management, parent-pom

Motive is to create a common dependency management repo for our team. Added the below pom samples for details :

**team-a-dependencies bom**

```
<groupId>teamA</groupId>
<artifactId>team-a-dependencies</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>xyz</groupId>
           <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <many-such-dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**Spring boot project**

```
<groupId>teamA</groupId>
<artifactId>team-a-sb-dep</artifactId>

<parent>team-a-dependencies</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
   some new and some dependencies from team-a-dependencies
</dependencies>
```

**DW project**

```
<groupId>teamA</groupId>
<artifactId>team-a-dw-dep</artifactId>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>teamA</groupId>
           <artifactId>team-a-dependencies</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <type>pom</type>
           <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
   some new and some dependencies from team-a-dependencies
</dependencies>
```

Is it a good idea if we both import and use as a dependency the below artifact id in some other project (OR) is there any other good approach to solve this usecase.

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <groupId>teamA</groupId>
   <artifactId>team-a-sb-dep</artifactId>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
   <groupId>teamA</groupId>
   <artifactId>team-a-sb-dep</artifactId>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you got confused by maven terminology, please check the explanation below...

According to [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms) the purpose of Bill of Materials (BOM) POMs is following:

> Imports are most effective when used for defining a "library" of
> related artifacts that are generally part of a multiproject build. It
> is fairly common for one project to use one or more artifacts from
> these libraries. However, it has sometimes been difficult to keep the
> versions in the project using the artifacts in synch with the versions
> distributed in the library. The pattern below illustrates how a "bill
> of materials" (BOM) can be created for use by other projects.
>
> The root of the project is the BOM POM. **It defines the versions of all**
> **the artifacts that will be created in the library**. Other projects that
> wish to use the library should import this POM into the
> dependencyManagement section of their POM

So, if we have multi-module project we may create BOM module in order to simplify dependency management, and the simple idea behind BOM is it is just an inventory of a library, and hence it should have a flat structure (no references to parent, no property placeholders, no references to other libraries - those libraries are transitive dependencies, otherwise instead of simplifying dependency management we are complicating it), below are the examples of  BOMs:

- [Spring Data](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-bom/2021.2.1/spring-data-bom-2021.2.1.pom) - note it provides information about spring data modules only
- [Jackson](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/jackson-bom/2.13.2.1/jackson-bom-2.13.2.1.pom) - not so good as spring data, but somehow acceptable

But neither `spring-boot-starter-parent` nor `spring-boot-dependencies` are `BOM`'s - I'm strongly discouraging you from importing them in dependency management.

What you are actually asking about is `Maven parent POM`/`super POM` which is exposed to the outside world, and here I would recommend you to think about how are you going to maintain it, because the broader scope it has than the less information/settings you may put into it, but the basic idea is: you either inherit `parent pom` or ignore it - maintaining hierarchical structures is always a pain in behind.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time for answering this. Wanted to ask why spring-boot-dependencies is not a bom? It conatins everything inside dependencyManagement

Comment: It declares third-party libraries which ultimately turns into some weird configurations like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72201785/how-maven-version-working-cant-update-ojdbc8-version, project reactor starts depending on various properties and the sequence of imports.

Comment: Can you also share your thoughts on how would you have approached the usecase given in the question

Comment: @hmims would you mind describing your goals first?

Comment: Our team owns multiple services. Some are written in Spring boot and some in drop wizard and in future we might consider some other framework as well for new services if needed. Hence, working on central dependency management. E.g. lombok can be used in both SB and DW but can be having different versions if needed else they will have the same version.

Comment: If that is not a controlled environment where InfoSec defines what software components you may use (and parent pom actually describes contents of Definitive Media Library) sharing parent pom across teams does not make sense: nobody likes the idea to update dependencies without good reason (security or serious bugs). Good usecases for parent pom are: microservices and plugins.